# how to calculate mean using apply for this dataframe in r

Tags: r, apply

Hi I have df (te_1_melt) like below and i want to calculate the mean of the each tis. How can i do that using apply in r?

```
                    samples variable       value       tis
1  GCIMB211_SHADE_INTERNODE      PC1 -0.10329820 INTERNODE
2       GCIMB211_SHADE_LEAF      PC1  0.25874619      LEAF
3       GCIMB211_SHADE_ROOT      PC1 -0.28965387      ROOT
4   GCIMB211_SHADE_SEEDLING      PC1  0.21416352  SEEDLING
5    GCIMB211_SHADE_SILIQUE      PC1  0.15468874   SILIQUE
6    GCIMB211_SUN_INTERNODE      PC1 -0.16332945 INTERNODE
7         GCIMB211_SUN_LEAF      PC1  0.22555539      LEAF
8         GCIMB211_SUN_ROOT      PC1 -0.24209723      ROOT
9     GCIMB211_SUN_SEEDLING      PC1  0.25053364  SEEDLING
10     GCIMB211_SUN_SILIQUE      PC1  0.25269207   SILIQUE
11   GCR500_SHADE_INTERNODE      PC1 -0.11863509 INTERNODE
12        GCR500_SHADE_LEAF      PC1  0.28048136      LEAF
13        GCR500_SHADE_ROOT      PC1 -0.31486321      ROOT
14    GCR500_SHADE_SEEDLING      PC1  0.04919059  SEEDLING
15     GCR500_SHADE_SILIQUE      PC1  0.06055899   SILIQUE
16     GCR500_SUN_INTERNODE      PC1 -0.16754805 INTERNODE
17          GCR500_SUN_LEAF      PC1  0.29588830      LEAF
18          GCR500_SUN_ROOT      PC1 -0.30497481      ROOT
19      GCR500_SUN_SEEDLING      PC1  0.19962128  SEEDLING
20       GCR500_SUN_SILIQUE      PC1  0.09154038   SILIQUE
```

Since i don't know how this is done using apply, i just did this..

> ```
> INT <- te_1_melt[grep("INTERNODE", te_1_melt$tis),]
> mean(INT[,3])
>
> LEA <- te_1_melt[grep("LEA", te_1_melt$tis),]
> mean(LEA[,3])
>
> ROOT <- te_1_melt[grep("ROOT", te_1_melt$tis),]
> mean(ROOT[,3])
>
> SEED <- te_1_melt[grep("SEEDLING", te_1_melt$tis),]
> mean(SEED[,3])
>
> SIL <- te_1_melt[grep("SILIQUE", te_1_melt$tis),]
> mean(SIL[,3])
>
> comb <- cbind(mean(INT[,3]), mean(LEA[,3]), mean(ROOT[,3]), mean(SEED[,3]), mean(SIL[,3]))
> colnames(comb) <- c("INTERNODE", "LEAF", "ROOT", "SEEDLING", "SILIQUE")
> comb
> comb_mlet <- melt(comb)
> comb_mlet
> ```

Even though i got what i wanted (see below), i know this is not efficient and just wanted to learn how this is done using apply. Anybody help?

```
> comb_mlet
  Var1      Var2      value
1    1 INTERNODE -0.1382027
2    1      LEAF  0.2651678
3    1      ROOT -0.2878973
4    1  SEEDLING  0.1783773
5    1   SILIQUE  0.1398700
```

Thanks
Upendra

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you want to use tapply.

```
> tapply(te_1_melt$value, te_1_melt$tis, FUN=mean)
 INTERNODE       LEAF       ROOT   SEEDLING    SILIQUE 
-0.1382027  0.2651678 -0.2878973  0.1783773  0.1398700
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `apply` here.You should use a sort of "group by" function.  For example, using `plyr`

```
> library(plyr)
> ddply(dat,.(tis),summarise,mm=mean(value))
        tis         mm
1 INTERNODE -0.1382027
2      LEAF  0.2651678
3      ROOT -0.2878973
4  SEEDLING  0.1783773
5   SILIQUE  0.1398700
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not `aggregate`?

```
aggregate(value ~ tis, data=df, mean)

#        tis      value
#1 INTERNODE -0.1382027
#2      LEAF  0.2651678
#3      ROOT -0.2878973
#4  SEEDLING  0.1783773
#5   SILIQUE  0.1398700
```